# ¿Cómo puedo leer línea por línea los resultados preliminares de una función en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, funciones, programación-funcional

Después de publicar esta pregunta en la versión en inglés

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959933/how-to-improve-a-seeker-for-databases-in-r-see-code/48985519#

Obtuve como respuesta este interesante código que permite crear la operación propia $. Me interesa saber cómo puedo explorar línea por línea la función con el fin de comprender del todo su lógica.

```
`%$%` <- function(df, seeker, cols=c("cyl","hp")) {
    strparts <- strsplit(seeker, "\\.")[[1]]
    sk <- ifelse(grepl("^[1-9]", strparts), paste0("==", strparts), strparts)
    s <- paste(paste0("df$", cols, sk), collapse="&")
    ans <- df[eval(parse(text=s)),]
    split(ans, ans[,cols])
}
```

Si alguien pudiera explicarme o referirme a algún material de consulta, lo agradeceré muchísimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos de a poco. En primer lugar se define un operador [infix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_de_infijo) con `%$%`, que es esto? básicamente es un operador binario que recibe dos parámetros. La forma más simple de entenderlo es comentar que las operaciones aritméticas básicas son operadores infix, veamos:

```
8 + 2 == `+`(8,2)
[1] TRUE
10 / 2 == `/`(10,2)
[1] TRUE
4 - 3 == `-`(4,3)
[1] TRUE
2 * 3 == `*`(2,3)
[1] TRUE
```

Es decir la suma por ejemplo, está definida como `` `+`(a,b) `` pero obviamente la forma habitual de usarlo es mediante la notación infija `a + b`. En tu ejemplo se define el operador `%$%` para poder usarlo así: `mtcars %$% "8.245"` aunque también podríamos invocarlo así: `` `%$%`(mtcars,"8.<245") ``, en algunos casos, no sé si en este, la notación infija es mucho más clara de leer.

Ahora veamos que hace la función. Podemos desarmarla y ejecutarla paso a paso para estudiarla en detalle.

En primer lugar vemos que la función tiene tres parámetros formales:

```
`%$%` <- function(df, seeker, cols=c("cyl","hp"))
```

Los dos parámetros obligatorios son un `data.frame` (`df`) y una cadena (`seeker`), el tercero `cols=c("cyl","hp")` tiene poco sentido ya que no lo podríamos usar con la notación infija, si, si invocamos la función de la forma estándar. Definamos ahora unas variables que hagan las veces de los parámetros:

```
seeker <- "8.<245"
cols <- c("cyl","hp")
df <- mtcars
```

Ahora empecemos desarmando el código paso a paso:

```
strparts <- strsplit(seeker, "\\.")[[1]]
strparts
[1] "8"    "<245"
```

Con esto hemos separado a partir del punto (usando expresiones regulares) en dos elementos de una lista la cadena `seeker`

```
sk <- ifelse(grepl("^[1-9]", strparts), paste0("==", strparts), strparts)
sk
[1] "==8"  "<245"
```

Con esto, normalizamos las expresiones, en el ejemplo agregamos el operador de igualdad en los casos que no lo tengan, si la expresión es solo un número sin ningún operador delante (`grepl("^[1-9]", strparts)`). Esto, ya vamos a ver, por que necesitamos construir una sentencia sintácticamente correcta que luego podamos evaluar.

```
s <- paste(paste0("df$", cols, sk), collapse="&")
s
[1] "df$cyl==8&df$hp<245"
```

Ahora esta más claro hacia dónde va la cosa, se arma la cadena a evaluar, concatenando los campos con el nombre del `data.frame` y con el operador `&` (`and`)

```
ans <- df[eval(parse(text=s)),]
ans
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
```

Y entonces se evalúa la expresión generada para usarla en una operación de selección. Por último solo para que la salida sea compatible con lo que solicitabas en la pregunta inicial, se dividen los resultados en una lista, cada elemento es un conjunto de observaciones separadas por `cyl` / `hp`

```
split(ans, ans[,cols])

$`8.150`
                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Dodge Challenger 15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin      15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2

$`8.175`
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2

....
```

Comment: Siempre claro y profundo en tus explicaciones. Te agradezco muchísimo, en serio.